# How to cancel CSharpScript.RunAsync

Tags: c#, task, roslyn, cancellationtokensource, csharpscript

How can I stop RunAsync?

```
CancellatioTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
//I thought that it's must work, but it don't
var script = CSharpScript.Create(code: someCode);
await script.RunAsync(cancelletionToken: cts.Token);

void button_click()
{
   cts.Cancel()
}
```

How else can I do this. And for why such methods need cancellationToken parameter?

Answer (score 3):

You must do it before the `await` call, which blocks execution until yout get results, e.g.:

```
var task = script.RunAsync(cancelletionToken: cts.Token);

cts.Cancel();

var result = await task;
```

Comment: cts.Cancel() is already in a separate function. It should also be on the UI thread.

Comment: Cancellation token can only interrupt `RunAsync` itself, while it's busy compiling. This will not interrupt running script.