# How to interrupt user-written script?

Tags: c#, csharpscript

Trying to run script (using Roslyn [Scripting API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples#delegate)):

```
var source = "while(true) { }";
return CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(source).Result;
```

It will run forever. How to interrupt it?

I don't mind using other script engine, though asking for one is off-topic. I've found similar questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41464734/1997232)), but they are not helpful.

Background: I want to add support for C# user-written scripts to my software. I want to run scripts in sandbox, so ability to interrupt scripts is vital. In past I had some experience with [CodeDOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/using-the-codedom), but I fail to find a way to interrupt scripts there too.

Thoughts:

- I could pre-process user-written text and insert my code (checks for `CancellationToken` and `return/throw`) after each line. But above example is immune to such technique and I'd then must go complex route of syntax parser (don't have experience with that, thoughts?).
- I could provide a method, which user have to explicitly call in his script problematic places (e.g. inside loops), but user may simply decide to ignore that.
- Is there a way to run script step-by-step? Sandbox-debugger mode? Then I'd be able to check external request to terminate script and stop debugging.

What are the other possibilities? Has anyone implemented *safe* user-written scripting yet?

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223259/how-to-cancel-csharpscript-runasync)?

Comment: @MindSwipe, I've seen this answer and ignored it (it has 2 downvotes). But.. it seems to work! It looks like internally `EvaluateAsync` method is already doing what I thought I have to do: it perform in parallel the cancellation check and somehow interrupts the script.

Comment: Hmm.. I did some testing and it doesn't interrupt always. It works only if `Cancel()` of token called **before** script is compiled (takes some time, especially for the first run). It does **not** interrupt the running script.